# How to prefer reads on secondaries in MongoDb

Tags: java, mongodb, replication, morphia

When using mongodb in a replica set configuration (1 arbiter, 1 primary, 2 slaves); how do I set a preference that read be performed against the secondaries and leave the primary only for writes? I'm using MongoDb 2.0.4 with Morphia. I see that there is a slaveOk() method, but I'm not sure how that works.

Morphia http://code.google.com/p/morphia/

**Details**
My Mongo is set with the following options:

```
mongo.slaveOk();
mongo.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.SAFE);
```

I am attempting to use the following (this may be answer -btw):

```
Datastore ds = getDatastore();
Query<MyEntity> query = ds.find(MyEntity.class).field("entityId").equal(entityId);
query.queryNonPrimary(); // appears equivalent to ReadPrefererence.secondary()
MyEntity entity = query.get();
```

Comment: vote it down without a comment, how helpful :(

Comment: The question does not show any research effort.

Comment: added it.. slaveOk.. will it work? no idea yet but it doesn't look right to me.

Comment: "no idea yet" - that's what I mean. Have you tried googling before asking the question?

Comment: i'm looking into query.queryNonPrimary() atm

Comment: yes, googled first; prefer answers from SO since they come with the experience of many developers.

Comment: anyhow just lashing out due to the trolling that goes on here; ask a question that you need an answer to and it gets less visibility due to people automatically down-voting it; this gets really annoying. Especially when there's no comment to explain or assist.

Comment: Wow dude, i'm starting to think less of you. if SO is not for assistance maybe they should update the about page: "With your help, we're working together to build a library of detailed answers to every question about programming." I for one certainly think this question would be very helpful for people in my situation; apparently you don't have a good answer but would rather knock others instead; how does that help anyone??

Comment: Man, please. [stackoverflow search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=mongodb+java+read+secondary), [google search](https://www.google.co.th/search?q=mongodb+java+read+secondary&aq=f&oq=mongodb+java+&aqs=chrome.0.59j57j0l2j61j60.2695&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8). First links in both searches contain answer to your question. Research effort, that's what I'm talking about.

Comment: Also [duckduckgo search](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mongodb+java+read+secondary)

Comment: Actually http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520439/how-to-configure-mongodb-java-driver-mongooptions-for-production-use/6521704#6521704 has the closest answer and is most helpful; but it says nothing about Morphia which is the ORM library noted in the question; hence none of those links have the answer. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: AFAIK, morphia is irrelevant here, since it relies on java driver for request routing. I might be wrong, though.

Comment: Added "morphia" tag.  It's documentation looks pretty thin on how it wraps the Java driver, you might need to look at the source.  The relevant Java driver doc is http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/ReadPreference.html and the general MongoDB docs are at: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/replication/#read-preference-modes

Comment: Yes, doc details are scarce for sure; but it is a really good library.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct answer, after much blood and sweat is as follows:

- To prefer all reads / queries hit the secondaries, only *slaveOk()* need be set
- To prefer only selected reads use secondaries, do not set *slaveOk()* and use *queryNonPrimary()* instead per query

It is also a good practice to set an appropriate write concern when using replica sets, like so:

```
mongo.setWriteConcern(WriteConcern.REPLICAS_SAFE);
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the current method (as per Java driver 2.8+) is to do

```
MongoOptions options = new MongoOptions();
options.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred());
```

then

```
mongo = new com.mongodb.Mongo(Arrays.asList(address1, address2), options);
```

This will make all connections prefer using secondaries, but will use the primary as a backup if the secondary is down or unavailable for some reason.

Comment: Good to know, I'm sure I'll run into this again if Mongo stays relevant

Comment: You can also set the read preference after creation of the mongo client like this `mongoClient.setReadPreference(ReadPreference.secondaryPreferred())`. `mongoClient.slaveOk()` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Use the "SECONDARY" read preference 
http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Read+Preferences+and+Tagging+in+The+Java+Driver

"SECONDARY : Read from a secondary node if available, otherwise error."

Comment: It's deprecated. Use `ReadPrefererence.secondary()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For the Java driver 3.6 the method is now

```
    MongoClientOptions l_opts =
            MongoClientOptions
            .builder()
            .readPreference( ReadPreference.secondary() )
            .build();

    ServerAddress l_addr = new ServerAddress( "localhost", 27017 );

    try
    (
            MongoClient l_conn = new MongoClient( l_addr, l_opts );
    )
    {
       ...
```