# mongo db connection time out

Tags: java, mongodb

The default connection time out  is 10 seconds in the mongo java driver . I stopped my mongo instance in my local and same time I am trying to connect mongo db from java .

Currently I am getting time out after 10000 ms exception .

My question is:
 Is it possible to get connection time out exception before the default time out(10000 ms) ?

Comment: Uhm, huh? Do you want something else to call for a timeout? Or do you wish to set the connection timeout to something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connection Time Out will function in a way that it will wait for the specified time, in your case 10 seconds.

No it is not possible to get the connection time out exception before the specified time.

References:

https://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/MongoOptions.html#connectTimeout

[How to configure MongoDB Java driver MongoOptions for production use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520439/how-to-configure-mongodb-java-driver-mongooptions-for-production-use)

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. The default connection time out for mongo java driver is 10000 ms , right?

Comment: https://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/MongoOptions.html#connectTimeoutsocketTimeout

public int socketTimeout
The socket timeout; this value is passed to Socket.setSoTimeout(int). 0 is default and infinite