# MongoDB client timeout settings

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am using **spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb** (version 2.3.1 RELEASE) to manipulate mongdb.

I notice that **timeout** is an important setting for client. I've searched over this forum and found various recommendations in terms of these settings, such as:

[How to configure MongoDB Java driver MongoOptions for production use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6520439/how-to-configure-mongodb-java-driver-mongooptions-for-production-use)

Howover, the above answer seems deprecated (last edited in 2013), as I cannot find settings like `socketTimeout` or `autoConnectRetry` in the latest 4.0.4 mongodb-driver-core.

Using mongodb 4.0.4 driver, we can notice several timeout settings under `SocketSettings`:

- `connectTimeout`: Seems to be socket connect timeout, default 10s
- `readTimeout`: Socket read timeout, default 0s

Can anyone give more explanations in terms of these *timeout* settings ?

Comment: Connect timeout applies to the initial connection on a socket. Socket timeout applies to subsequent read & write operations.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/current/tutorials/ruby-driver-create-client/#socket-timeout

Comment: @D.SM, thanks for the reply. I'am using mongodb server 4.0.10, it seems that socket timeout setting has disapeared, I am using mongodb java-driver-core-4.0.4, in SocketSetting, I only found: 1). connectTimeoutMS, default is 10s, 2). readTimeoutMS default 0, 3). receiveBufferSize 4). sendBufferSize

Comment: Link to driver documentation where the timeouts are described please.